# How to calculate balance along opening balance in SQL

Tags: sql, database, accounting

Can anybody help me writing a SQL query to find the balance with opening balance on top as well?

Desired output:

[image: 1]

It currently does not show "Opening Balance" but I want it as well.

Here is the sample data:

```
create database test

use test


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Ledger]
(
    [Ledg_ID] [int] Primary Key IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Ledg_p_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Ledg_Pay_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Ledg_FarmerID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Ledg_Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Ledg_Desc] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Ledg_Debit] [money] NOT NULL,
    [Ledg_Credit] [money] NOT NULL,
    [Ledg_Remarks] [varchar](255) NULL
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Ledger] ([Ledg_p_ID], [Ledg_Pay_ID], [Ledg_FarmerID],[Ledg_Date],
                                [Ledg_Desc], [Ledg_Debit], [Ledg_Credit],[Ledg_Remarks])
VALUES (1, NULL, 2, '2021-05-06',
        'Purchase', 500, 0.00, ''),
       (NULL, 2, 2, '2021-05-07',
        'Payment', 0.00, 300, ''),
       (NULL, 3, 2, '2021-05-08',
        'Payment', 0.00, 200, '')
```

Comment: What does "opening balance on top" mean?  It seems to have nothing to do with your desired results.

Comment: Opening Balance means,  Balance of previous date from starting date.
Suppost, I have requested 10-05-2021 to 15-05-2021, then Balance of 09-05-2021 will be my opening balance

Answer (score 0):

This might depend on the vendor of DB that you are using, but many support the OVER clause.
see explanation [here](https://codingsight.com/calculating-running-total-with-over-clause-and-partition-by-clause-in-sql-server/):

using OVER you can create a cumulative sum of a column.
so your query will look something like this:

```
SELECT ID, p_ID, FarmerID, Datee, Description, Debit, Credit,
SUM (Debit - Credit) OVER (ORDER BY Datee) AS Balance
FROM tbl_Ledger
```

Comment: Imbar, You are right but if we have more than 1 entry on the same date. then it's creating problem while calculating balance

Comment: @M.HamzaSajjad - You must have some way to distinguish between, and sequence, multiple entries on the same day, correct? Whatever those columns are, they should be included in the (ORDER BY) clause. (If you have no way of sequencing multiple entries on the same day, then the data model is insufficient to establish a starting or ending balance on each transaction because, by definition, you would not know the order of those transactions. I'm assuming this is not the case.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the "opening" balance on each row, just subtract out what happens on the row:

```
SELECT l.*,
       SUM(Debit - Credit) OVER (ORDER BY Datee) AS Balance
       SUM(Debit - Credit) OVER (ORDER BY Datee) - (Debit - Credit) AS Opening_Balance
FROM tbl_Ledger l
```